# After being operated on his eyes,

Tags: grammar

Can I say

> "After being operated on his eyes, the nurses took the patient to his room."

I have looked up the meaning of "operate on" and I have found out that "operate + on + someone" who has the operation or + a part of the body. For example, Doctor James has operated on me or on my eyes. If we change the sentence into the passive voice, I will find out that I have been operated on by Dr. James. And my eyes have been operated on by Dr. James. If we mix two sentences together, we will notice the following sentence: I have been operated on on my eyes.
Is what I have written true or not?

Comment: After the operation on my eyes. After Dr. James operated on my eyes. After my eyes **were operated on by Dr. James**. After having my eyes operated on by Dr. James.

Answer (score 4):

No, your sentence has two errors.

If his eyes were operated on, you need to say:
**After his eyes were operated on...**

Then to follow that you have to say something about him, not about the nurses:
**After his eyes were operated on (by Dr James), he was taken to his room by the nurses.**

Otherwise you have what is known as a dangling participle.

A classic example would be:
**After robbing the store, the policeman arrested a thief.**
You have to ask "Who robbed the store?"
To correct the sentence you have to use the passive voice:
**After robbing the store, a thief was arrested by a policeman.**
The same rule applies in your case.

Finally, while you can say:
**After he was operated on (by Dr James), he was taken.....**
you can't insert **his eyes**.
After he was operated on, you have to say what happened to him.

Comment: No, you don't have to ask "Who robbed the store?" No sane person would do so, except perversely, either as a joke, or to prove their "superiority" over people who use a real language as opposed to their made-up version with pointless rules.